# How to update RecyclerView on foreground Activity from its background Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I am working on a chat app. Let's say I have two activities: 
**1. MainActivity** 
   It contains online friends list, clicking them will open next activity. I have some overridden methods to get the chat messages in this activity.
**2. ChatActivity** 
   It contains the chat conversation between two users. It has a RecyclerView whose data needs to be refreshed when a new chat message is received in MainActivity.

My current implementation is:
1. MainActivity has list of RecyclerView adapters and I am updating data in the adapter when a chat message is received using **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**.
2. Opening ChatActivity and waiting for the new data to be populated on the RecyclerView is not happening. But once I go back to MainActivity and then come again on the respective ChatActivity, I can see the new chat messages.

Is there an efficient way of handling this scenario? Any design pattern for this? Any help would be highly appreciated.
If you need the codes, I can provide.

Comment: Are you calling an api for the data? or using database ?

Comment: I am calling API for the data. The overridden method on MainActivity provides me the data.

Comment: Why are you calling the api on the `MainActivity`? You can directly call the api on the `ChatActivity` to get the data.

Comment: Actually, it is the listener which provides data to the app. I do not need to call the API explicitly. The app gets notified when a new message is received. And, message from all the users are received here, so it has to be the MainActivity.

Comment: So you can override the same method in the `ChatActivity` as well to receive the updates.

Comment: Well I tried that as well. Sadly, only one activity (the first activity implementing the listener) gets to override the listener, it seems.

Comment: Perhaps make a datahandler class which subscribes to your listener to get the data, and then pass your datahandler between your activities so they both get the data from there?

Comment: @Quinn, your suggestion sounds promising. Any pseudocode on how to achieve it?

Answer (score -1):

Use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), it is based on publisher subscriber pattern

Comment: its is classical antipattern that makes project's behavior unpredictable after scaling.